# How to solve "File name too long" while uploading local Image to Firestore and Firebase Storage in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload local images to Cloud Firestore and Firebase storage.

The **PACKAGES** I'm using are

- [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker) to choose an image from local
- [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) to transfer files as blob to Firebase storage

Here's the 2 functions I'm using:

```
export const uploadPost = async (postImageUri) => {

        return new Promise(async(res, rej) => {

                const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
                
                fs.readFile(postImageUri,'hello','base64')
                .then(async (data) => {
                    console.log('data from RNFetchBlob', data);
                    const storageRef = storage().ref(`posts/images`).child(`${data}`);
                    
                    try {
                        storageRef.putFile(data,{contentType: 'image/jpeg'})
                        .on(
                            storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
                            snapshot => {
                                console.log('snapshot', snapshot.state);
                                console.log('progress', (snapshot.bytesTransferred)/(snapshot.totalBytes)*100);

                                if(snapshot.state === storage.TaskState.SUCCESS){
                                    console.log('SUCCESS')
                                }
                            },
                            error => {
                                console.log('Image upload error', error);
                                rej(error)
                            },
                            () => {
                                storageRef.getDownloadURL()
                                .then((downLoadUri) => {
                                    console.log('File available at: ', downLoadUri);
                                    // addPostInfo
                                    res(downLoadUri)
                                })
                            }
                        )
                    }catch{err => console.log(err) }
                })

                
        } )
}

export const addPostInfo = async (post) => {
    
    console.log('post.postImageUri in addPostInfo', post.postImageUri.slice(10))
    const remoteUri = await uploadPost(post.postImageUri);
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        firestore()
        .collection('posts')
        .add({
            id: post.id,
            createdAt: post.date,
            description: post.description,
            image: remoteUri,
            location: post.checkin_location
        })
        .then(ref => {
            console.log('Finish adding in addPostInfo', ref)
            res(ref)
        })
        .catch(err => rej(err))
    })
}
```

And in the main screen, I directly send the `image`'s path to the `addPostInfo`:

```
const _onSharingPost = () => {
        const postCreated = {
            id: 'alkdgjhfa;oiughaoghus',
            postImageUri: postImageUri,
            date: _getCurrentDate(),
            description: postDescription,
            checkin_location: checkInLocation
        }
        
        postActions.addPostInfo(postCreated);
    }
```

The `path` is like this:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F58/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/950379202
```

**ERROR**

```
...base64 string --> File name too long
```

*It got down to the `SUCCESS` part of the `upLoadPost` function but then still got error*

`I HAVE TRIED:`

- Change the path --> cut off the `content://`
- Use XMLHttpRequest to send the blob to the `upLoadPost` to send that to the storage

As far as I know, the problem must be the `base64` string converted from the image path. I know we need to change that to blob or something, but I don't know how. I can't find where this can be specified in `rn-fetch-blob` docs

**PLEASE HELP ME**